# Implicit declaration of function error.... but did it like they said?

Tags: c, compiler-errors, cs50

I copied code from a class example so I could play with it. So far I can't even get it to run as is.

Here it is:

```
#include <cs50.h>

int x = GetInt(); 
switch(x)
{
    case 1:
    printf("One!\n)")
    break;
    case 2:
    printf("Two!\n")
    break;
    case 3:
    printf("Three!\n")
    break;
    default:
    printf("Nah...\n")
}
```

The error is:
sswb.c:3:9: **error: implicit declaration of function 'GetInt'** is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
int x = GetInt();

The help thingy says **"You seem to have an error in sswb.c on line 3. By "implicit declaration of function 'GetInt'", clang means that it doesn't recognize
GetInt. Did you forget to #include <cs50.h> (in which GetInt is declared) atop your file?"**

But I have so.... I'm lost.

Help! Please tell me what's right under my nose and I'm not seeing?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] - that is, at the very least the surrounding function where you have this code. At a glance it looked to me as if `int x` was declared at file scope, but now I realize that's probably not the case.

Comment: (a) You may be using the wrong version of `cs50.h`. Does the one you have contain `get_int` or `GetInt`? (b) All executable code in C must be inside a function. You must start a function such as `int main(void) {` before you can use statements like `switch`. The `int x = GetInt();` must be inside the function too. Although it is a declaration, not a statement, it calls `GetInt`, which executes code. Declarations outside functions can only use constants, not executable code.

Comment: So, according to the help thing that I can call on, which tells me " Did you forget to #include <cs50.h> (in which GetInt is declared) atop your file?", I believe that it is indeed, GetInt that's definied in the (library? Right, that's what it's called?). But I don't know how to get to it and check for myself, though. ////// It wasn't inside a function. Trying again. Thank you!

Comment: EDIT: so the help thing lead me astray, it was get_int that was defined in the library i was including. I added the semi colons I forgot, put everything into an int main(void) function and it's working. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

here is something simpler

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    int x;
    scanf("%d",&x);
    switch(x)
    {
        case 1: printf("one!\n");
        break;
        case 2: printf("two!\n");
        break;
        case 3: printf("three!\n");
        break;
        default: printf("error!\n");
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Delivering undocumented and unexplained code for a homework assignment is not answering a question. It does not explain concepts to a person who is learning, it does not explain the mistakes that were made, it does not explain the error messages they received.

Answer (score -1):

It seems the error occurred because you forgot to specify a string as an argument of the function. Something

```
int x = GetInt( "Enter an integer: " );
```

Or use

```
int x = get_int( "Enter an integer: " );
```

if `GetInt` does not exist.

Pay attention to that you may not place statements as the switch statement or declarations that are not initialized by constant expressions in a file scope. They shall be inside functions.